# How to consolidate / eliminate PHP includes for class files

Tags: php, class, optimization, hierarchy

I have multiple files that I keep including individually.  I want to just put them all in one file to decrease file I/O and just have one include.

**Update**

Ended up using an auto-loader here is the php.net [reference](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php).  Now I don't have to explicitly include each file and according to the reference the files are lazy loaded.

Comment: Why don't you want to use autoloading? It generally solves this problem quite nicely.

Comment: Having a hard time undertanding what are lanugage contructs and what are functions in PHP.  Does the autoloader just call more code that requires PHP files anyways and if so is it more costly.  That was one concern.

Comment: The autoloader is a function that you register. It is called every time you reference a class that does not exist. If the filename can be deduced from the class name (e.g., Foo lives in Foo.class.php), then you can include that file and continue on. It's likely to be insignificantly slower than if you were to include exactly the things you needed up front, but the convenience more than makes up for it. Bad algorithms and inefficient database schemas are the types of things that are costly... not whether or not you use an auto loader.

Comment: I'm using an auto-loader now....it claims that it performs lazy initialization as well...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PHP will parse the file. PHP will probably register the classes, and will in any case parse and syntax check the file. But this might still be faster than loading separate files. More separate file I/O will be slower, though it will require less memory because only the needed files are loaded.

I wouldn't worry about either, because memory consuption for the classes alone is close to nil. File I/O will probably not be a problem either. You may have APC cache, which keeps compiled versions of the PHP files into memory, and if not, your OS will probably have some caching features which cause often used files to be loaded faster.

Comment: So, I will consolidate into one file then.  Best case the compiled version will be kept in memory and each separate call will simply pull as needed each object with out reparsing and resyntax checking.  Also I'll make some gains by only loading only one file.  Memory consumption is moot.  This is correct?

Comment: That is correct. I admit I like to put separate classes in separate files to keep functionality separated and readable. I use an autoloader to load the files. This works well too and I like to have my code structured this way, but do have an APC cache to my exposal ;-)  For another site I don't, but it has much less visitor. I didn't even bother to measure performance there. It performs well enough, and readability is important to me too. I don't want to put 100.000 lines of code in a single file.

Comment: And though I'm sure a single file will be faster for you, I'd suggest you make the same consideration. Readability and structure is important if you want to maintain your code in the long run. Premature optimization is the root of all evil. You probably won't measure very large performance differences.

Comment: Right...the code base is small enough, and I'v picked unique identifiers so I can use Control F to get around, instead of scrolling.

Answer (score 3):

While nothing is stopping you from consolidating all of your class objects into a singe file, to do so would be against basic code design philosophies and also eventually create a monolithic file to manage.

If you are thinking about making a single class to require(), I would suggest keeping your individual classes as their own files, and having your consolidate.php look more like this:

```
<?php
    /** consolidate.php **/
    require "class.session.php";
    require "class.general.php";
?>
```

As for the PHP handling, calling require() or include() on a file does not actually call any constructing methods on objects. That said, it does include the entirety of the file. For example, including session.php (2KB) and general.php (3KB) would only include 5KB. Including everything could increase that size dramatically depending on your code base.

Answer (score 2):

You should absolutely *not* put all your classes in one file if you're developing them.  It makes things very difficult to maintain.  A separate file for each class means you know exactly where to go to change something.  And yes, PHP *will* spend time parsing classes you don't use.  Why don't you want to use an autoloader?  They make things so much easier, and it's not like they're a lot of overhead or anything.

If you're worried about IO efficiency, then cache your code.

Addressing naming conventions, I suggest you look at a pretty widely accepted standard here:

http://groups.google.com/group/php-standards/web/psr-0-final-proposal?pli=1

Comment: So if I cache my code, then PHP will know only to create the objects that are needed, i.e. those that are called, even if thier corresponding classes are in one file?

Comment: See the [topic on merging multiple files into one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1463277/merging-multiple-php-script-into-a-single-file). I believe maintenance is one, but merging files before moving to production is a separate question. Of course it can be messed up, some level of quality is a must.

Comment: @Chris: when you cache it, it parses the PHP file into a form that can be easily used by PHP and stores it in memory.  After this point, the only time it will use any functions or classes is if they're called in the code.